# Which assertion to use for a simple comparison between two variables in jmeter?

Tags: jmeter

I have a test which stores results in two variables and I want to do an assertion which returns a fail if they are not equal.

I know there are a number of different assertions available. I'd like to know which would be most appropriate for a simple comparison like this and how to use it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Beanshell Assertion](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_Assertion) will do the trick for you, relevant code will be:

```
String var1 = vars.get("first");
String var2 = vars.get("second");

Failure = !var1.equals(var2);

if (Failure) {
  FailureMessage = "Variables are not equal. Expected \"" + var1 + "\" , actual:\"" + var2 + "\"";
}
```

Replace `first` and `second` with your variable names (**without** `${}`)

- `Failure` - is a pre-defined boolean variable, if it is "true" - impacted sampler(s) are considered as failed, otherwise - successful.
- `FailureMessage` - custom string to describe the failure

See [How to Use JMeter Assertions in Three Easy Steps](https://blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-assertions-3-easy-steps) for more comprehensive information on using assertions.